# How can I execute several command lines using Java Runtime?

Tags: java, process, runtime, processbuilder

I realize the long single line code below looks ridiculous but please treat it as pseudo code. I have a script that executes 11 command lines in a row. I've successfully implemented it using AutoItX (similar to Selenium), but doing so is really only a surface-level solution. Simulated button clicks leave room for error and interruption and just doesn't feel like clean code. I want the command line itself to execute the script using the Java runtime environment.

```
sendCommand("cmd cd " + homepath + "\\" + a + "&&" + "mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://"+ homepath + "/.m2/repository" + "&&" + "1" + "&&" + c + "&&" + b + "&&" + c + "&&" + uuid.toString() + "&&" + "Y" + "&&" + "cd " + homepath +"\\"+ a +"\\" + b + "&&" + "mvn clean install" + "&&" + "cd " + homepath +"\\" + a + "&&" + "cd " + homepath +"\\" + a +"\\" + b + "\\" + b + "-plugin" + "\\target" + "&&" + "jar -xvf " + zipDirectory + "&&" + "cmd cd " + homepath +"\\" + a +"\\" + b + "\\" + b + "-plugin" + "\\target\\" + "\\META-INF\\maven\\" + c + "\\" + b + "-plugin" + "&&" + "copy pom.xml " + pluginDirectory + "&&" + "cd " + pluginDirectory + "&&" + "rename pom.xml " + b + "-plugin-1.0.0.pom" + "&&" +  "color 0a");

private static void sendCommand(String text) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(text);
}
```

Can ProcessBuilder accept more than two command lines? I've never seen it used that way before. For example, here are two lines:

```
sendCommand("homepath/plugins", "mvn", "archetype:generate", "-DarchetypeCatalog=file://homepath/.m2/repository");

private static void sendCommand(String workingDirectory, String... command) throws IOException {
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).directory(new File(workingDirectory)).start();
    int status = proc.waitFor();
    if (status != 0) {
        // Handle non-zero exit code, which means the command failed
    }
}
```

How can I run 11 lines in the same process, and execute each one only after the previous one has been executed?

Comment: Start a command shell and feed the commands to it via its standard input.

Comment: You might look into tools such http://expectj.sourceforge.net/ (or maybe something newer)

Comment: Why not creating a script (e.g. run_mvn.cmd) with all the commands and validations inside and run this via `ProcessBuilder`? As this is a very platform/shell specific task I would hand voer all the main work to the cmd/shell. Because they are build for such a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .vbs file which calls batch file. In batch file write all your commands.
Call the .vbs file from process builder.

```
String ExecutionPath = "pathTo/run.vbs";
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + ExecutionPath);

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        process.destroy();
    }
}));
process.waitFor();
```

Your .vbs file looks like this which calls the batch file and command prompt running the batch is not shown.

Dim WinScriptHost

Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim oFSO

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sScriptDir = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & sScriptDir & "\run.bat" & Chr(34), 0

Set WinScriptHost = Nothing

Comment: Why the intermediate .vbs file?

Comment: Directly running the batch file from process builder pops up command prompt window. If you don't want the command prompt window to pop up use intermediate vbs. If cmd window pooping up is not your concern then directly call your batch file.